# Are there any negative side-effects of blocking svchost.exe from making outbound connections?

Tags: windows-10, firewall, windows-update, svchost

**Background**: I would like to definitely prevent Windows 10 from ever updating unless I manually allow it to. I thought of the idea of using the firewall to block outbound connections from the Windows Update service, thus preventing it from downloading an update. However, I've found that the Windows Update service is bundled into this "svchost.exe" process which apparently has other functionality as well.

**My question**: What potential negative side-effects might there be from blocking all outbound connections from svchost.exe? What else does svchost.exe need to connect to the internet for? Is there a list somewhere?

**A followup question**: if there are some negative side-effects, is there a more refined firewall rule I could implement that would still definitely 100% never allow Windows to update itself but would avoid those side-effects?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes there is. If you want to ask about a specific one  ...

Comment: Svchost exe could be any program or service that is using svchost to go to the internet, so blocking it is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks - good to know. Would you mind giving me an example of a program or service that might use svchost to go to the internet? Or, any recommendations for a more refined firewall rule that would accomplish the same goal?

Comment: Type this in a command prompt. `wmic service where "startname='NT Authority\\NetworkService'" get caption,description /format:list`

Comment: You can disable Windows Update is the services control panel applet. Windows Update manages it. Background Intelligent Transfer Service downloads files. TrustedInstaller installs the updates. Note your question asks something you don't want to know.